# Tar: добавление в архив по фильтру и по времени

Tags: tar, ubuntu

Здравствуйте.

1. Необходимо добавить в архив все папки и файлы, кроме описанных каталогов (и их содержимого) и файлов в файле list.txt, это возможно? Если да, то файлы в list.txt должны быть написаны по одному на строчку и относительно корня?
2. Как добавить в архив только файлы, созданные или измененные за последние два часа?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Воспользоваться исключающей опцией --exclude=PATTERN, но у вас там какой то список еще, я бы на вашем месте лучше формировал список того что надо а не наоборот, например find-ом поискать то что надо, а дальше xargs и собственно tar.
2. Тут опять же find. `find /path/to/dir -mmin -120 | xargs tar -cvf arhive.tar`